# Deleting or adding child entities to parent with Spring Boot Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have the following entities:

```
class Question {
    String question;
    QuestionType type;
    List<QuestionOption> options;
}

class QuestionOption {
    String option;
    Question question;
}
```

My frontend webpage that handles editing a `Question` also does the adding/updating/deleting of the child `QuestionOption`'s. So let's say I add a new option and change the question string itself, I would want this to be changed in a single request.

My current code for updating the `Question` entity looks like this:

```
    public Question update(Question original, Question updated) {
        original.setQuestion(updated.getQuestion());
        original.setType(updated.getType());
        original.setOptions(updated.getOptions());
        return questionRepository.save(original);
    }
```

This however does not add/update/delete the child `QuestionOption`'s of the `Question` and I'm not really sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

To update an entity, you first need to get Managed instance of that entity, update it's values and then save it.

```
public Question update(Integer originalQueId, Question updated) {
        Original original=questionRepository.findById(originalQueId);
        original.setQuestion(updated.getQuestion());
        original.setType(updated.getType());
        original.setOptions(updated.getOptions());
        return questionRepository.save(original);
    }
```

I am just assuming here that you have some Id i.e. primary key for Question. Using it, you can fetch the original data from database. This instance then becomes a managed instance which can be then used to update the data in DB.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing right now. The `original` Question is retrieved from database in the controller and the object is then passed on this update method.

Comment: Updating the other fields works fine but the child entities don't work.